# Why is my C program not working correctly?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

This is my program:

```
int main(){

    struct Koordinaten {
        float x;
        float y;
    }Vektor[3];

    typedef struct Koordinaten Koordinaten;

    float A[3], s, b; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        char d;
        if(i == 0)
            d = 'A';
        if(i == 1)
            d = 'B';
        if(i == 2)
            d = 'C';

        printf("Please enter the coordinates of the %c vector:\nx: ", d);
        scanf("%f", &Vektor[i].x);
        printf("\ny: ");
        scanf("%f", &Vektor[i].y);

        printf("Values of the %c vector x: %f  y: %f\n\n", d, Vektor[i].x, Vektor[i].y);

        A[i] = sqrt(Vektor[i].x * Vektor[i].x + Vektor[i].y * Vektor[i].y);
        printf("The length of the vector %c is: %f\n\n", d, A[i]);
    }

    s = 1/2 * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]);
    printf("s = %f\n", s);

    b = sqrt(s * (s - A[0]) * (s - A[1]) * (s-A[2]));
    printf("The area is: %f", b);
}
```

As you can see I want to take three vectors and give the area of the Vectors. It works perfectly since the line with the s variable. My program only gives me 0 for the value of s, but it has to be 7.5!

Comment: input, expected output and actual output, please.

Comment: Change `s = 1/2 * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]);` to `s = 1/(2 * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]));`

Comment: `char d;
        if(i == 0)
            d = 'A';
        if(i == 1)
            d = 'B';
        if(i == 2)
            d = 'C';` -> `char d = 'A' + i;`

Comment: thank you very much to all of you i found the mistake.

Comment: As a general comment about naming, I would suggest being consistent with things like capitalization, e.g., your `Vektor` is an array but the style is the same as `Koordinaten`, which is a type. Also, most of the single-character names (`s`, `b`) could be made longer and more descriptive, in particular the `s` may at first glance imply that it's "some string".

Comment: regarding: `1/2`  this is an `int` divide and results in 0.  Suggest: `1.0f/2.0f` so it is a `float` divide and evaluates to .5

Comment: the posted code does not compile! It is missing the statements: `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <math.h>`

Comment: regarding the function: `sqrt()`  it returns a `double` which is not what is wanted.  suggest using: `float sqrtf(float x);`  which returns a `float`

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
  s = 1/2 * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]);
```

is the same as

```
  s = (1/2) * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]);
      ^^^^^^--------------------------This is an integer division, with a result 0, 
                                      so, 's' will always have a value 0.
```

You need to change that to

```
 s = 1.0/2 * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]);
     ^^^^^^-----------------------------now this is floating point division.
```

to ensure floating point division.

Comment: Or just  `s = .5 * (A[0] + A[1] + A[2]);`.

Comment: @glglgl Sure, just wanted to keep the same syntax so the problem is more visible. :)

Comment: regarding the expression:  `1.0/2`  this is a `double` division, which is not what is wanted.  Suggest: `1.0f/2.0f`